# Execute script to download and unzip file on a remote computer, it runs successfully but nothing downloaded

Tags: c#, powershell

I have created a C# function to execute a PowerShell script to download and unzip a file from a remote computer. It runs successfully, but nothing is downloaded.

Below is my current code:

```
        public static string RemotePSExecution(string ipAddress, string username, string password, string psFilePath)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (Char c in password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }
            PSCredential creds = new PSCredential(username, securePassword);

            WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo();
            connectionInfo.ComputerName = ipAddress;
            connectionInfo.Credential = creds;

            String psProg = File.ReadAllText(psFilePath);
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
            runspace.Open();

            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.Runspace = runspace;
                ps.AddScript(psProg);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                try
                {
                    var results = ps.Invoke();
                    foreach (var x in results)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(x.ToString());
                    }
                    result = sb.ToString().Trim(); 
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error occurred in PowerShell script", e.InnerException);
                }
            }
            runspace.Close();
            return result;
        }
```

And my PowerShell script:

```
$url = "https://<internal website>/xp.zip"
$zipFile = "Downloads\xp.zip"
$targetDir = "Downloads\UnZipFiles\"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $zipFile 
Expand-Archive $zipFile -DestinationPath $targetDir -Force
```

If I run the PowerShell script directly on the remote VM, then the file is downloaded and unzipped successfully. But if I run the script using C# then nothing is downloaded.

Another thing, the C# function works for the below PowerShell script:

```
(Get-Service -DisplayName "*Service").Status
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying an absolute path instead of relative for zipfile and targetdir in the PS file. Your file probably gets downloaded in some temp or appdata folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The file is downloaded and unzipped as expected after I specified an absolute path for zipfile and targetdir in the PS file. Thanks a lot, @Gaël James. I really appreciate your help.

Here is my updated PS file:

```
$url = "https://<internal website>/xp.zip"
$zipFile = "C:\Users\<current user>\Downloads\xp.zip"
$targetDir = "C:\Users\<current user>\Downloads\UnZipFiles\"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $zipFile 
Expand-Archive $zipFile -DestinationPath $targetDir -Force
```